# Is there any difference between the Garbage Collector performance for Windows 2008 server and Windows 8.1 OS?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have tried to export my record to excel and dispose the exported elements in windows 8 OS. I can able see the memory reduced details in Task Manager. But this same code i have used in Windows 2008 server OS. There is no memory difference after disposed the exported elements. I can use the below code to clear Garbage collector.

```
ExportedElement = null;
GC.SuppressFinalize(obj);
```

Can you please provide the reason for this changes, if anyone knows about this?

Comment: The question is irrelevant. You should not be setting things to `null` in .NET, and `SuppressFinalize` has nothing to do with invoking the garbage collector. You are trying to "help" too much. Just let the garbage collector do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are differences in the behavior of garbage collection among the different windows platforms and .NET Frameworks.

No, GC.SuppressFinalize() just advices the CLR not to call the object's finalizer when collecting the object. The method does neither force the garbage collection nor prevent the specific object from being collected (or whatever you mean with 'clear garbage collector').

For further information, I recommend to read the Microsoft documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx